# What is the purpose of the directory ".Caches - TTS DEACTIVATED" in user/library/

Tags: macos

There is an offensively large directory (25GB) here: 
`/Users/john/Library/.Caches - TTS DEACTIVATED`

I did a quick search and found [one page in Spanish](https://forum.italiamac.it/topic/544053-caches-tts-deactivated/) that had one answer that suggested TTS=Text To Speech. Even if it's required, although it says deactivated, it would be good to have some consensus on what it's for.

Comment: .caches is a hidden *cache* folder. Doubtful that removing it would be a problem but you could copy it somewhere else and reboot your Mac. If no problems in a day or two I would toss it.

Comment: @Steve-Chambers looking through it, there have been changes made recently - within the last hour. There are also many empty directories that are a few years old - from removed applications. I am more curious what "TTS DEACTIVATED" means when it's attached to the end of a cache directory and understanding what the system is doing.

Comment: Caches are rebuilt if needed again. By all means investigate to your heart's content, but I have been doing support for a long time and am more of an "empty the caches and see what happens" kind of guy. Caches are accessed regularly, that is not surprising. Running down all that info may not fix your problem or even satisfactorily answer your question. But it is in a cache directory, which are designed (Win/Mac/Linux/Unix) to be cleared from time to time, manually or automatically. Your call on what is more important, getting some space back or leaving things be.